# Add synthetic data functions to a package instead of datasets

Tags: r, package

I am developing a package to analyse the behaviour of many animals over several days.
I would like to provide realistic examples of some of my functions (which crush and plot a fair amount of data). 
The CRAN policy is that packages should be small (<5MB). So I am thinking of making a series of function to generate synthetic data that could be effectively treated (and documented) as package data.

Ideally, I would define functions like:

```
dataset1 <- function(){
    ...
    return(df)
}
```

Then, I could simply call:

```
data(dataset1)
```

Is that possible and/or recommended?

Thanks,

Comment: It's OK to provide a function that can be called to generate random data. No need to pretend it's a dataset or force anyone to use `data()` - is there some reason you think that's beneficial?

Comment: I suggest using `set.seed()` if you want people to play with a reproducible toy example.

Comment: @MrFlick, I was thinking about that mainly for documentation purposes, but I am happy as well for the user to call functions to make add hock data, thanks!